# Does a Full-Text Index work well for columns with embedded code values

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, sql-server-2012, full-text-indexing

Using SQL Server 2012, I've got a table that currently has several hundred-thousand rows, and will grow.

In this table, I've got a nvarchar(30) field that contains Medical Record Number (MRN) values. These values can be just about any alphanumeric value, but are not words.

For Example,

```
DR-345687
34568523
*45612345;T
```

My application allows the end user to enter a value, say '456' in the search field.  The application would need to return all three of the example records.

Currently, I'm using Entity Framework 5.0, and asking for a `field.Contains('456')` type of search.

This always takes 3-5 seconds to return since it appears to do a table search.

**My question is:** Would creating a Full Text Index on this column help performance?  I haven't tried it yet because the only copy of the database that I have with lots of data in it is currently in QA trials.

Looking at the documentation for the Full Text Indexes it appears that it is optimized around separate **words** in the field value, so I am hesitant to take the performance hit to create the index without knowing how it is likely to affect my query performance.

Answer (score 1):

EF won't use the T-SQL keywords needed to access the SQL Server full text index (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142571.aspx#queries) so your solution won't fly without more work.

I think you would have to create a SProc to get the data using the FTI and then have EF call this. I have a similar issue and would be interested to know your results.

Andy

Comment: Being interested in a solution is not the answer. So please, if you have a question do not hesitate to ask one here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask